# Problems with starting Oozie workflow

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, oozie

I have a problem starting a Oozie workflow:

Config:

```
<workflow-app name="Hive" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.4">
    <start to="Hive"/>
    <action name="Hive">
        <hive xmlns="uri:oozie:hive-action:0.2">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <configuration>
                <property>
                    <name>oozie.hive.defaults</name>
                    <value>hive-default.xml</value>
                </property>
            </configuration>
            <script>/user/hue/oozie/workspaces/hive/hive.sql</script>
              <param>INPUT_TABLE=movieapp_log_json</param>
              <param>OUTPUT=/user/hue/oozie/workspaces/output</param>
            <file>hive-default.xml#hive-default.xml</file>
        </hive>
        <ok to="end"/>
        <error to="kill"/>
    </action>
    <kill name="kill">
        <message>Action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>
    <end name="end"/>
</workflow-app>
```

File content:

```
[root@localhost ~]# hadoop fs -cat /user/hue/oozie/workspaces/hive/hive.sql
SELECT * FROM ${INPUT_TABLE}
```

And I get error:

```
2013-03-11 06:53:10,196 INFO org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand: USER[hdfs] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[Hive] JOB[0000025-130310103217365-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000025-130310103217365-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] Start action [0000025-130310103217365-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] with user-retry state : userRetryCount [0], userRetryMax [0], userRetryInterval [10]
2013-03-11 06:53:10,197 WARN org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand: USER[hdfs] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[Hive] JOB[0000025-130310103217365-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000025-130310103217365-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] [0000025-130310103217365-oozie-oozi-W@:start:]Action status=DONE
2013-03-11 06:53:10,197 WARN org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand: USER[hdfs] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[Hive] JOB[0000025-130310103217365-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000025-130310103217365-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] [0000025-130310103217365-oozie-oozi-W@:start:]Action updated in DB!
2013-03-11 06:53:10,351 INFO org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand: USER[hdfs] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[Hive] JOB[0000025-130310103217365-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000025-130310103217365-oozie-oozi-W@Hive] Start action [0000025-130310103217365-oozie-oozi-W@Hive] with user-retry state : userRetryCount [0], userRetryMax [0], userRetryInterval [10]
2013-03-11 06:53:11,244 WARN org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.HiveActionExecutor: USER[hdfs] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[Hive] JOB[0000025-130310103217365-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000025-130310103217365-oozie-oozi-W@Hive] credentials is null for the action
2013-03-11 06:53:13,734 INFO org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.HiveActionExecutor: USER[hdfs] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[Hive] JOB[0000025-130310103217365-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000025-130310103217365-oozie-oozi-W@Hive] checking action, external ID [job_201303101032_0029] status [RUNNING]
2013-03-11 06:53:13,838 WARN org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand: USER[hdfs] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[Hive] JOB[0000025-130310103217365-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000025-130310103217365-oozie-oozi-W@Hive] [0000025-130310103217365-oozie-oozi-W@Hive]Action status=RUNNING
2013-03-11 06:53:13,839 WARN org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand: USER[hdfs] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[Hive] JOB[0000025-130310103217365-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000025-130310103217365-oozie-oozi-W@Hive] [0000025-130310103217365-oozie-oozi-W@Hive]Action updated in DB!
2013-03-11 06:53:41,459 INFO org.apache.oozie.servlet.CallbackServlet: USER[-] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] APP[-] JOB[0000025-130310103217365-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000025-130310103217365-oozie-oozi-W@Hive] callback for action [0000025-130310103217365-oozie-oozi-W@Hive]
2013-03-11 06:53:41,570 INFO org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.HiveActionExecutor: USER[hdfs] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[Hive] JOB[0000025-130310103217365-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000025-130310103217365-oozie-oozi-W@Hive] action completed, external ID [job_201303101032_0029]
2013-03-11 06:53:41,610 WARN org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.HiveActionExecutor: USER[hdfs] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[Hive] JOB[0000025-130310103217365-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000025-130310103217365-oozie-oozi-W@Hive] Launcher ERROR, reason: Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.HiveMain], exit code [10001]
2013-03-11 06:53:41,807 INFO org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionEndXCommand: USER[hdfs] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[Hive] JOB[0000025-130310103217365-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000025-130310103217365-oozie-oozi-W@Hive] ERROR is considered as FAILED for SLA
2013-03-11 06:53:41,877 INFO org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand: USER[hdfs] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[Hive] JOB[0000025-130310103217365-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000025-130310103217365-oozie-oozi-W@kill] Start action [0000025-130310103217365-oozie-oozi-W@kill] with user-retry state : userRetryCount [0], userRetryMax [0], userRetryInterval [10]
2013-03-11 06:53:41,877 WARN org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand: USER[hdfs] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[Hive] JOB[0000025-130310103217365-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000025-130310103217365-oozie-oozi-W@kill] [0000025-130310103217365-oozie-oozi-W@kill]Action status=DONE
2013-03-11 06:53:41,877 WARN org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand: USER[hdfs] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[Hive] JOB[0000025-130310103217365-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000025-130310103217365-oozie-oozi-W@kill] [0000025-130310103217365-oozie-oozi-W@kill]Action updated in DB!
2013-03-11 06:53:42,030 WARN org.apache.oozie.command.coord.CoordActionUpdateXCommand: USER[hdfs] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[Hive] JOB[0000025-130310103217365-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[-] E1100: Command precondition does not hold before execution, [, coord action is null], Error Code: E1100
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Error is from Oozie, workflow did not launched by coordinator i.e, if you started Oozie with root user stop the service and restart the oozie with User which you installed Oozie. Now re-run the workflow.

This would solve your problem!!