# OOZIE:PIG job execution getting failed

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig, oozie, cloudera-cdh

I am new to `OOZIE` and was trying to run a `PIG` script using the `OOZIE` workflow. Below is the pig script named `first.pig`:

```
A = LOAD '/user/jas/pigip' USING PigStorage(',');
B = FOREACH A GENERATE $0;
STORE B INTO '/user/jas/pigop';
```

Below is the `workflow.xml`:

```
<workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.2" name="PIGACTION">
 <start to="pig-node"/>
 <action name="pig-node">
    <pig>
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
        <script>first.pig</script>
    </pig>
  <ok to="end"/>
  <error to="fail"/>
 </action>
   <kill name="fail">
   <message>Pig Script failed!!!</message>
   </kill>
   <end name="end"/>
</workflow-app>
```

Below is the `job.properties`:

```
nameNode=hdfs://localhost:8020
jobTracker=localhost:8021
queueName=default
oozie.libpath=/user/oozie/shared/lib
oozie.wf.application.path=${nameNode}/user/my/pigact
```

For running the workflow:

1) I uploaded the `first.pig` and `workflow.xml` in the location `/user/my/pigact`

2) Input file (a simple CSV) is uploaded in the path `/user/jas/pigip`

For running the job, below is the command I used:

`oozie job -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie -config job.properties -auth SIMPLE -run`

The job got submitted and then KILLED. below is the `Job Log`:

```
2016-03-02 11:35:01,463  INFO ActionStartXCommand:539 - USER[training] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[PIGACTION] JOB[0000009-160301223816814-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000009-160301223816814-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] Start action [0000009-160301223816814-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] with user-retry state : userRetryCount [0], userRetryMax [0], userRetryInterval [10]
2016-03-02 11:35:01,463  WARN ActionStartXCommand:542 - USER[training] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[PIGACTION] JOB[0000009-160301223816814-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000009-160301223816814-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] [***0000009-160301223816814-oozie-oozi-W@:start:***]Action status=DONE
2016-03-02 11:35:01,464  WARN ActionStartXCommand:542 - USER[training] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[PIGACTION] JOB[0000009-160301223816814-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000009-160301223816814-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] [***0000009-160301223816814-oozie-oozi-W@:start:***]Action updated in DB!
2016-03-02 11:35:01,524  INFO ActionStartXCommand:539 - USER[training] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[PIGACTION] JOB[0000009-160301223816814-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000009-160301223816814-oozie-oozi-W@pig-node] Start action [0000009-160301223816814-oozie-oozi-W@pig-node] with user-retry state : userRetryCount [0], userRetryMax [0], userRetryInterval [10]
2016-03-02 11:35:02,411  WARN PigActionExecutor:542 - USER[training] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[PIGACTION] JOB[0000009-160301223816814-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000009-160301223816814-oozie-oozi-W@pig-node] credentials is null for the action
2016-03-02 11:35:04,170  INFO PigActionExecutor:539 - USER[training] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[PIGACTION] JOB[0000009-160301223816814-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000009-160301223816814-oozie-oozi-W@pig-node] checking action, external ID [job_201603012236_0015] status [RUNNING]
2016-03-02 11:35:04,293  WARN ActionStartXCommand:542 - USER[training] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[PIGACTION] JOB[0000009-160301223816814-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000009-160301223816814-oozie-oozi-W@pig-node] [***0000009-160301223816814-oozie-oozi-W@pig-node***]Action status=RUNNING
2016-03-02 11:35:04,295  WARN ActionStartXCommand:542 - USER[training] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[PIGACTION] JOB[0000009-160301223816814-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000009-160301223816814-oozie-oozi-W@pig-node] [***0000009-160301223816814-oozie-oozi-W@pig-node***]Action updated in DB!
2016-03-02 11:35:12,210  INFO CallbackServlet:539 - USER[-] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] APP[-] JOB[0000009-160301223816814-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000009-160301223816814-oozie-oozi-W@pig-node] callback for action [0000009-160301223816814-oozie-oozi-W@pig-node]
2016-03-02 11:35:12,409  INFO PigActionExecutor:539 - USER[training] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[PIGACTION] JOB[0000009-160301223816814-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000009-160301223816814-oozie-oozi-W@pig-node] action completed, external ID [job_201603012236_0015]
2016-03-02 11:35:12,434  WARN PigActionExecutor:542 - USER[training] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[PIGACTION] JOB[0000009-160301223816814-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000009-160301223816814-oozie-oozi-W@pig-node] Launcher ERROR, reason: Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.PigMain], exit code [2]
2016-03-02 11:35:12,705  INFO ActionEndXCommand:539 - USER[training] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[PIGACTION] JOB[0000009-160301223816814-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000009-160301223816814-oozie-oozi-W@pig-node] ERROR is considered as FAILED for SLA
2016-03-02 11:35:12,794  INFO ActionStartXCommand:539 - USER[training] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[PIGACTION] JOB[0000009-160301223816814-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000009-160301223816814-oozie-oozi-W@fail] Start action [0000009-160301223816814-oozie-oozi-W@fail] with user-retry state : userRetryCount [0], userRetryMax [0], userRetryInterval [10]
2016-03-02 11:35:12,795  WARN ActionStartXCommand:542 - USER[training] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[PIGACTION] JOB[0000009-160301223816814-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000009-160301223816814-oozie-oozi-W@fail] [***0000009-160301223816814-oozie-oozi-W@fail***]Action status=DONE
2016-03-02 11:35:12,795  WARN ActionStartXCommand:542 - USER[training] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[PIGACTION] JOB[0000009-160301223816814-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000009-160301223816814-oozie-oozi-W@fail] [***0000009-160301223816814-oozie-oozi-W@fail***]Action updated in DB!
2016-03-02 11:35:12,904  WARN CoordActionUpdateXCommand:542 - USER[training] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[PIGACTION] JOB[0000009-160301223816814-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[-] E1100: Command precondition does not hold before execution, [, coord action is null], Error Code: E1100
```

Please suggest what went wrong, I am unable to identify the issue.

**EDIT**

Capturing the snapshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Console URL from the 3rd image (highlighted) is  displaying the 4th image. Please suggest.

This is the log I got:

```
>>> Invoking Pig command line now >>>


Run pig script using PigRunner.run() for Pig version 0.8+
Apache Pig version 0.10.0-cdh4.1.1 (rexported) 
compiled Oct 16 2012, 10:15:57

Run pig script using PigRunner.run() for Pig version 0.8+
1196 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main  - Apache Pig version 0.10.0-cdh4.1.1 (rexported) compiled Oct 16 2012, 10:15:57
1199 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main  - Logging error messages to: /var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/mapred/mapred/local/taskTracker/training/jobcache/job_201603012236_0030/attempt_201603012236_0030_m_000000_0/work/pig-job_201603012236_0030.log
1463 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine  - Connecting to hadoop file system at: hdfs://localhost:8020
1472 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine  - Connecting to map-reduce job tracker at: localhost:8021
1674 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt  - ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal error. name

<<< Invocation of Main class completed <<<

Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.PigMain], exit code [2]

Oozie Launcher failed, finishing Hadoop job gracefully


Oozie Launcher ends


stderr logs

Details at logfile: /var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/mapred/mapred/local/taskTracker/training/jobcache/job_201603012236_0030/attempt_201603012236_0030_m_000000_0/work/pig-job_201603012236_0030.log

Pig logfile dump:

Pig Stack Trace
---------------
ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal error. name

java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: name
    at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserStringStream.<init>(QueryParserStringStream.java:32)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.tokenize(QueryParserDriver.java:198)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:166)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.parseQuery(PigServer.java:1594)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.registerQuery(PigServer.java:1545)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.registerQuery(PigServer.java:545)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processPig(GruntParser.java:970)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:386)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:189)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:165)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.exec(Grunt.java:84)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:430)
    at org.apache.pig.PigRunner.run(PigRunner.java:49)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.PigMain.runPigJob(PigMain.java:282)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.PigMain.run(PigMain.java:222)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMain.run(LauncherMain.java:37)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.PigMain.main(PigMain.java:76)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMapper.map(LauncherMapper.java:472)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:50)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:393)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:327)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1332)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)
================================================================================
Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.PigMain], exit code [2]
```

Comment: This can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15336923/problems-with-starting-oozie-workflow

Comment: I checked this post earlier but its of no use: I am able to run an `OOZIE` workflow with `MapReduce`, hence starting the `OOZIE` server should not be an issue. I am facing this issue for both `PIG` and `HIVE`. Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looking at `QueryParserStringStream.java`, it extends ANTLRStringStream. Now if antlr is missing, you should get ClassNotFoundError not NoSuchFiledError. Only possible reason that I can think of is that there is a different version of antlr in classpath at run-time, which is causing this error.

Comment: Removing the duplicate jar fiiles from the oozie shared lib (From HDFS) and using the correct version of antlr jar files resolved the issue for me. Thanks again !!!

Comment: May I know which specific jar file you have deleted?

Answer (score 1):

The error that you are seeing is the failed result of the oozie launcher mapper job, which is carrying you pig script to gather resources and run it actually on your cluster. It basically mimics your command line grunt functionality.

If you have your oozie web console available, you can click on the killed action on your workflow job, which will show you a job URL. The job URL actually points to your oozie launcher mapper job, whose logs you can check to understand what went wrong.

Comment: when you click on the killed workflow, you should be able to see the actual pig action that errored out. if you click on the errored out pig action, you should be able to see a `Console URL`, which will open the launcher job

Comment: I am unable to see the `Console URL` tab, i am using `cloudera 4.1.1`. Also, I have run the Pig script in local and it is working fine, hence no issues with the Pig Script. I an getting the same error when I try to run an OOZIE workflow with a HIVE job, bur MapReduce job is running fine with OOZIE workflow. Please suggest.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the killed job? Once you clicked on the failed action, you should be able to see three tabs

Comment: noticed something similar here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17179200/pig-exception-on-simple-load      can you check if you have hive enabled on the same machine, which most probably is ?

Comment: Yes I do have HIVE enabled in same system. How to disable hive? I tried `echo $HIVE_HOME` and nothing gets displayed in terminal, but HIVE is enabled and running fine in my system. Then I tried `export HIVE_HOME=` and re-run the oozie job but still I am getting the same error. Please let me know how to disable HIVE in my system.

Comment: look at QueryParserStringStream.java, it extends ANTLRStringStream. Now if antlr is missing, you
should get ClassNotFoundError not NoSuchFiledError. Only possible reason
that I can think of is that there is a different version of antlr in
classpath at run-time, which is causing this error.

Comment: `hadoop fs -ls /user/oozie/shared/lib/antlr*` gives: 
`/user/oozie/shared/lib/antlr-2.7.7.jar,
 /user/oozie/shared/lib/antlr-3.0.1.jar,
/user/oozie/shared/lib/antlr-runtime-3.0.1.jar,
/user/oozie/shared/lib/antlr-runtime-3.4.jar` 
I can see two versions of `antlr` and `antlr-runtime` - Is this the reason for this exception. Which one to use? Please suggest.

Comment: Ok I resolved this issue by removing `antlr-3.0.1.jar` and `antlr-runtime-3.0.1.jar` from my oozie share lib folder which is uploaded in hdfs. I removed these two jars because these are the two versions I can see oozie needs in the pig directory of oozie installation. Thanks a lot for the help :)

Comment: Please post this answer so that I can accept your answer and credit you the points for helping:) Also, please let us know in your answer how you debug this issue to conclude that the issue is with the jar :)

Answer (score 0):

There was an error while executing the pig script. Here is the error in the logs:

> 2016-03-02 11:35:12,434  WARN PigActionExecutor:542 - USER[training] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[PIGACTION] JOB[0000009-160301223816814-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000009-160301223816814-oozie-oozi-W@pig-node] Launcher ERROR, reason: Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.PigMain], exit code [2]

I don't see any obvious issues in you script, can you run the script in MapReduce mode and check if you get any errors?

`pig -x mapreduce first.pig`

Comment: is tez enabled as a default execution engine for PIG in your setup?

Comment: No tez is not yet enabled. Is it required to resolve this issue? To add a little more information, I am running it on a Cloudera cluster and I am getting the same error for HIVE jobs as well.